Pass specific protocol type as argument to a function
Is it possible to pass a specific protocol type (not an instance conforming to a protocol) as an argument to a function?  If so, what would the syntax for this be?
For example, given:
protocol A {}
protocol B {}
protocol C {}

I would like to have a function into which I can pass A.Protocol, B.Protocol, or C.Protocol (or any other protocol, for that matter).  For context, the project I am working on has a robust framework for injecting dependencies that are registered by class type and can be overridden in tests.  I would like to add the the ability to generically inject based on conformance to a protocol.
That is inject(SomeProtocol.Protocol) would return an object implementing SomeProtocol if one had already been registered with the injector, or nil. I'm just not sure that Swift semantics provide a way to express this notion.

I am gussing you tried the basic syntax: func f<T: A /* or B or C*/> (x: T) and it didn't fit your needs. So what is it that you need to do? be more specific?

No, Swift metatypes are not very well developed, so it doesn't stretch that far. On the other hand, have you considered that if the point is to be able to specify a procotol by means of a parameter, a simple constant would do? You could pass an instance of an enum:
enum WhichProtocol {
    case protocolA
    case protocolB
    case protocolC
}

The recipient could then behave differently by switching on the case of the WhichProtocol parameter. Of course it would have to "know" how to get from .protocolA to ProtocolA to "an object implementing ProtocolA or nil", but that doesn't seem so horrible.
